# How to access node acl across multiple modules?

Tags: javascript, node.js, acl

I am having some trouble understanding how to use the [Node ACL](https://github.com/OptimalBits/node_acl) with mongoose module. I can get it running fine as long as everything is in one file. However how do I access the acl instance in other modules if I wanted to break up the routes into separate files?

I can get acl working with the following code just fine. It initializes, creates the collections in the database, and adds permissions to the user.

```
// App.js
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const node_acl = require('acl');
const User = require('./models/User');

mongoose.connect(/* connection string */);

acl = new node_acl(new node_acl.mongodbBackend(mongoose.connection.db, '_acl'));
acl.allow([
  {
    roles: ['guest'],
    allows: [{ resources: 'login', permissions: 'get' }],
  },
  {
    roles: ['admin'],
    allows: [{ resources: '/users', permissions: '*' }]
  }
]);

var user = User.findOne({username: 'coffee'}, (err, user) => {
  console.error(user.id);
  acl.addUserRoles(user.id, 'admin');
});
```

What I can't figure out is how to properly access the acl instance in another module like this.

```
// routes/foo.js
const acl = require('acl');
const router = require('express').Router();

// initialize acl ?

router.route('/', acl.middleware(/* rules */), (req, res) => {
  // route logic
});

module.exports = router;
```

This code yields the following error: `TypeError: acl.middleware is not a function`.

Do I need to create a new instance of acl using the database connection in each route module? If so what is the best way to to get the connection from Mongoose again? If not, or is there a way to pass it to each route?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As IOInterrupt suggested you should create a helper module, here's is how i made it work:

**security.js**

```
'use strict';

var node_acl = require('acl'),
    log = require('../log')(module),
    redis = require('../db/redis'),
    acl;

var redisBackend = new node_acl.redisBackend(redis, 'acl');
acl = new node_acl(redisBackend, log);
set_roles();

function set_roles () {

    acl.allow([{
        roles: 'admin',
        allows: [{
                resources: '/api/conf',
                permissions: '*'
            }
        ]
    }, {
        roles: 'user',
        allows: [{
            resources: 'photos',
            permissions: ['view', 'edit', 'delete']
        }]
    }, {
        roles: 'guest',
        allows: []
    }]);

    acl.addUserRoles('5863effc17a181523b12d48e', 'admin').then(function (res){
        console.log('Added myself ' + res);
    }).catch(function (err){
        console.log('Didnt worked m8' + err);
    });

}

module.exports = acl;
```

i called it for the first time on my app.js

**app.js**

```
// .. a bunch of other stuff 
var app = express();

require('./config/express')(app);
require('./config/routes')(app, jwtauth.jwtCheck);
require('./config/security'); // just like this

connect().on('error', console.log)
         .on('disconnected', connect)
         .once('open', function (){
            log.info('Connected to DB!!!');
         });
// .. a bunch of other stuff
```

Then on my route file conf.js like this:

**conf.js**

```
    log = require(libs + 'log')(module),
    acl = require('../config/security'),
    isauth = require(libs + 'auth/isAuthorized'),
    redis = require('../db/redis');

//               This is where the magic ensues
router.get('/', acl.middleware(2,isauth.validateToken,'view'), function (req, res) {
    Conf.findById(req.query.id).then(function (conf) {
        return res.json(conf);
    }).catch(function (err) {
```

Don't worry about calling the mongo connection to being called at each import, since here you'll be using require('../config/security') so they will all get the same object because exports is cached during the first time you call it at **app.js**. I mean, this will **not** create a mongodb connection each time.

Comment: I'm getting a `Unhandled rejection TypeError: Cannot read property 'collection' of undefined` error.  I think it's because I'm using mongoose like the OP is using but you are using redis.  I can wrap it with `mongoose.connection.on` but I'm not sure how to extract the acl instance.

Answer (score 3):

You can share object by request variable:

**app.js:**

```
acl = new node_acl( new node_acl.mongodbBackend(mongoose.connection.db, '_acl'));
// add this before routers:
app.use( function( req, res, next) {
  req.acl = acl;
  next();
});
```

**routes/foo.js:**

```
router.route('/', (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.acl);
  // route logic
});
```

Comment: In that example `acl.middleware()` is still undefined until you get the request object in the handler, so the middleware still won't work correctly, right?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest creating a helper module, which initializes the acl.  You could then require it within any other modules that may require it, such as your routes.

Comment: If I write a helper module that can initialize acl, wouldn't that create dozens of connections to the database? Or does it just connect once?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `app.locals` to store global object within the application.,

in your `app.js`:

```
app.locals.acl = acl;
```

then in any request, you can get it back by `req.app.locals.acl`:

```
route.get('/some-resource', function (req, res, next) {

    let acl = req.app.locals.acl
    ...
}
```

Checkout `app.locals` document at https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#app.locals