# Node ACL not working when trying to assign permissions

Tags: javascript, node.js, acl

I am having trouble is assigning user roles and permission using [Node ACL](https://github.com/OptimalBits/node_acl#addUserRoles) . I am new to MEAN stack, so I really do not have a good understanding of how node or javascript framework works.

I am trying to create a registration system when a user is registered he will be assigned `user` role along with `user permissions`.

Here is my code so far

*** server.js ***

This is my node application entry point

```
var acl;
var app = express();
//Importing other required files
var databaseConfig = require('./config/database');
var routes = require('./routes/index');



//Connect to the database
//Set up default mongoose connection
mongoose.connect(databaseConfig.url,{ useNewUrlParser: true },_mongo_connected);


function _mongo_connected( error, db ) {
    if (error){
        console.log(chalk.red('Could not connect to database. Error '+error));
    } else{
        console.log(chalk.green('Connected to database '+ config.db.uri));
        var mongoBackend = new node_acl.mongodbBackend(db);
        acl = new node_acl( mongoBackend);
        global.ACL = acl;  // I set it global so i can use it else where
        set_roles();
    }
}

function set_roles() {
    acl.allow([
        {
            roles: 'admin',
            allows: [
                { resources: '*', permissions: '*' }
            ]
        }, {
            roles: 'user',
            allows: [
                { resources: '/api/user',permissions:['get', 'put', 'delete'] }
            ]
        }, {
            roles: 'guest',
            allows: []
        }
    ]);
    acl.addRoleParents( 'user', 'guest' );
    acl.addRoleParents( 'admin', 'user' );
}
```

My route file *** routes/index.js***

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var authController = require('../app/Controllers/AuthController');
router.post('/registration',authController.registration);
```

Now the ***AuthController.js ***

```
const User =  require('../Models/User');
exports.registration = function (req, res) {
    let errors = [];

    if (!req.body.email ){
        errors.push('Please enter your email');
    }



    if (errors.length){
        //There are errors
        res.json({
            code:420,
            success:false,
            msg:'One or more filed are missing',
            errors:errors
        });
    } else{
        let newUser = new User({
            name:req.body.name,
            email:req.body.email,
            password:req.body.password,
            firstName:req.body.firstName,
            lastName:req.body.lastName,
            role:'user'
    });
        User.addUser(newUser,(error,user)=>{
            if (error){
                res.json({
                    code:420,
                    success:false,
                    msg:'Failed to register user.Probably this email/username is already taken.',
                    errors:error.errors
                });
            }else{
                console.log('Hello');
                console.log('User id',user._id.toString());
                ACL.addUserRoles(user._id.toString(), user.role, err => {
                    if (err) {
                        console.log(err);
                    }
                    console.log('Added', user.role, 'role to user', user.firstName, 'with id', user._id);
                });
                res.json({
                    code:200,
                    success:true,
                    msg:'User registered successfully'
                });
            }
        })
    }
};
```

When I hit the API user get registered into the database after that nothing happens, whereas I was expecting it to assign `user` permissions to the user.
Can anyone please help me.

And as you can see I set `ACL` as a global variable but I do not think that is how I should be doing.

I followed tutorials from here : https://blog.codecentric.de/en/2018/07/protecting-resources-with-node_acl-module-in-nodejs/

[How to access node acl across multiple modules?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35341396/how-to-access-node-acl-across-multiple-modules)

Answer (score 0):

In server.js of my node application, acl was implemented by using accessControl().

```
const isAuthenticated = (req, res, next) => {
      if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
          next()
      }
      res.redirect('login')
   }
function accessControl() {
  const nodeAcl = new ACL(new ACL.memoryBackend())

  nodeAcl.allow([{
    roles: 'admin',
    allows: [{
      resources: ['/home','/api/users', '/api/posts'],
      permissions: '*',
    }],
  }, {
    roles: 'user',
    allows: [{
      resources: ['/api/users', '/api/posts'],
      permissions: 'get',
    }],
  }, {
    roles: 'guest',
    allows: [],
  }])

  // Inherit roles
  //  Every user is allowed to do what guests do
  //  Every admin is allowed to do what users do
  nodeAcl.addRoleParents('user', 'guest')
  nodeAcl.addRoleParents('admin', 'user')

  nodeAcl.addUserRoles('joe', 'admin')
  nodeAcl.addUserRoles('john', 'user')
  nodeAcl.addUserRoles(0, 'guest')

  return nodeAcl
}

const access = accessControl()
```

After assigning permission to roles, I used acl middleware when getting home url.

```
 app.get('/home', [isAuthenticated, access.middleware()], (req, res) => {

        res.render(__dirname + '/views/home.ejs');
    });
```

This works for me.I hope it for you too.